# Mojave Wi-Fi app using 2GB of memory

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, wifi, memory, mojave

What is the application Wi-Fi, and why is it gobbling 2GB of memory? Running latest version of macOS Mojave 10.14.1 on a 2018 MacBook 15" with 16GB of memory total.

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue on 10.14.4. Using Activity Monitor to quit seems to reset the memory usage back down to <5 mb with no ill effects that I've noted so far. I don't see anything interesting in the "open files and ports" tab or in "sample process."

Comment: There's a newer thread with a pretty comprehensive answer. Let me know if you edit this so that it's covering different ground or has a more narrow question edited in.